# Firefox adding additional 1px to block element with border-radius

Tags: css, firefox, rendering, pixel

Oddly enough, and just since recently (perhaps since an Update?) Firefox (16.0.1) gives me an additional white or blank pixel row within elements that have a border-radius set.

I have tried modifying a lot of properties, such as line-height, overflow and more, but nothing seems to work and for other odd reasons, i am not able to reproduce the problem outside of the framework in which i render these buttons. However, i have tried disabling the CSS reset i use, i have tried disabling certain other values in the outlying CSS, using Firebug, but to no avail.

As i don't know how to reproduce it, i have put together a graphic demonstrating the issue:

[image: Demonstration of Problem]

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and is aware of a possible fix?

Edit: I now also noticed that other elements are messed up too. This is definitely a new development. Even inputs seem wrong and setting the line-height for them, does not affect the outcome. See additional graphic:

[image: Additional Graphic]

Here is the CSS tree for the input field viewed in the second graphic:

```
.dynamicForm-componentEdit .componentLabel input.long {
    width: 320px;
}

.dynamicForm-componentEdit .componentSettings textarea, .dynamicForm-componentEdit .componentLabel textarea, .dynamicForm-componentEdit .componentSettings input, .dynamicForm-componentEdit .componentLabel input {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF 0%, #FAFAFA 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    width: 130px;
}
input {
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Verdana;
    outline: 0 none;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.dynamicForm-componentEdit {
    color: #AAAAAA;
}
.interfaceBlock-content {
    color: #666666;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
}
body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,Geneva;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 100.01%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Edit #2: The problem seems to be related to CSS3 gradients. I changed the CSS from:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F7F7F7 0%, #E5E5E5 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

to:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;
```

See this graphic:

[image: Graphic Number 3]

The problem disappears when using a normal background!

Comment: Please post enough CSS to at least try to replicate the issue.

Comment: Here is your image's CSS using a `button`: http://jsfiddle.net/h7MAB/ Obviously, it doesn't look the same; to me, the `line-height` looks wrong (should it be `10px`?); are there other style properties being applied you haven't shown?

Comment: I was about to post some more CSS code - i'll try the above suggestions first. Edit: The issue definitely is not caused by a specific border-radius i tried 8px, also tried different height, no avail - i'll post some more CSS in a minute.

Comment: You might also try setting a `background-color`, maybe `background-color: red;`, which show if it's the background. I don't see the linear gradient is "resetting", which I think the others are suggesting, mainly because the top of the gradient is not the same color (light gray versus white).

Comment: With Firebug, you can also look at the `Computed` tab and look for anything that's `#fff` or `white`. It's definitely white. Also look for other `border-` settings.

Comment: Thank You Jared! Thanks to your good input it is now clear that it has to do with the gradient! It came to my mind when looking at the computed CSS. I will edit my question and add another graphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by applying:

```
background-clip: padding-box
```

to all elements affected by the problem.

I am not sure if this is the best approach, but it definitely works. The problem is that all the gradient definitions will overwrite the setting - it can not just be applied to all DIVs for instance.

A correct definition therefore looks like this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F7F7F7 0%, #E5E5E5 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box transparent;
```

If anyone can think of a more elegant and effective approach, please feel free to post a comment or answer.

**Edit:** After further research i found out that padding-box does fix the described  rendering issue but that the whole problem occured because of something else and seemed to affect paddings which is why the text in the input field (see upper graphic #2) was not centered vertically (as it should be).

Finally i found the culprit - and i don't quite understand why it is one at all: **Helvetica**

Once i switched to Arial, all problems were simply gone.

Must be a font rendering issue then, or something in the font metrics messes up Firefox's renderer?

Comment: I couldn't quite think of what that property was called (I was thinking it was a `border-` property).

Comment: solved another problem for me where corners with `border-radius` were rendered wrongly in FF https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6981682/chromevsfirefox.png

Answer (score 0):

My last answer was removed and I assume it's because I gave the same one on another task wich featured the same issue. So if you want to see how I solved this issue then see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13273215/1806644

Comment: This should be a comment.